# Carousel slides are not sliding

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I've got the following problem:

I tried to create a carousel for my website. I copied the code from the bootstrap website and just put in some pictures to see if it's working.

But it doesn't. I see the first picture that should be active, but that's it. I can't click through the carousel. Can anybody help?

Thank you in advance!

HTML code:

```html
<!-- Carousel -->

<div class="bd-example">
  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="images/wueste.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="images/wueste-links.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="images/wueste-rechts.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you also include the <script>? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/download/#cdn-via-jsdelivr

Comment: The [example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#with-captions) on the bootstrap site uses <button>s, not <li>s. It works fine.

Comment: I changed <li> into <button>, now it works. Thank you!